# DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. Using Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Having this error after deploying my code to cloud, using google appengine, i use objectify indexing for my filtering.

here is my java class (Entity) file containing the index

```
@Entity
public class Session{
   @Index private Integer year;
   @Index private Key<Institute> institute;
  //some other manipulation goes below
   }
```

When am trying to call a list of entity from datastore using objectify like this

```
ofy().load().type(Session.class).filter("institute",t).order("year").list();//order by year
```

it throws the below error on my console , the below image shows it , sorry not too clear

[image]

Comment: I would love to see how this is solved facing the same issue .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add suggested index definition to your `datastore-indexes.xml` file. If you don't have this file, you need to create it in /war/WEB-INF/ folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">

    <datastore-index kind="Session" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="institute" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="year" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Note that most index definitions can be auto-genereated when you test your app on the development server, but sometimes it's not easy to test every possible use case and manual definitions may be an easier option.

Comment: thanks , have done that, done mvn update of it , when i check google cloud console indexes it is not showing it there , the error still persist

Comment: It's not showing up at all, or it says "building"? If you don't see it at all, that means you did not deploy this file. Check the deployment log.

Comment: what i read in objectfy wiki, they said it takes days or hours depending on the system, since it is a low priority task. Or is there a separate way to update indexes

Comment: You should see the index definition immediately after you upload it. It may take some time to build - you should see "building" next to the new index definition.

Comment: did not see any building, saw a command to update indexes , `mvn appengine:update_indexes`. returning error of ancestor being **false**

Comment: Just saw the indexes now . Thanks @andrei-volgin